# Reduce Multidimensional Array Into One Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Simply to said I need help, how to make multidimension array into one array without change the key array?

From these :

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [554] => a
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [561] => b
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [574] => c
            )

    )
```

Into these :

```
Array
(
    [554] => a
    [561] => b
    [574] => c
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you be able to describe what your challenge is? Right now, your question is not in a good format yet. If you want to receive some help, having a good format is important. If necessary, search some questions having many upvotes. You can learn how to write better questions. :)

Comment: O sorry, I thought I ask it properly, if this question not useful then how I delete it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$array = array(
            array(554 => "a"),
            array(561 => "b"),
            array(574 => "c")
        );


function getL2Keys($array) {
    foreach($array as $sub)
        $result[] = array_keys($sub);

    return call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_values($result));
}

$array = array_combine(getL2Keys($array), call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_values($array)));
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [554] => a
    [561] => b
    [574] => c
)
```

Comment: It works, I thought I must use array_reduce, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `array_walk_recursive` for problems like this:

```
function flatten($array)
{
    $temp=array();
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($item, $key) use (&$temp) {
        $temp[$key]=$item;
    });

    return $temp;
}

$a = array(
    array(
        564=>'a',
    ),
    array(
        561=>'b',
        array(
            562=>'d',
            array(
                563=>'e',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    array(
        574=>'c',
    ),
);

$b = flatten($a);
print_r($b);
```

This is my output:

```
Array
(
    [564] => a
    [561] => b
    [562] => d
    [563] => e
    [574] => c
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll just have to post this, since all the other current answers are so terrifically overcomplicated:

```
$result = array_reduce($array, function ($result, $array) { return $result + $array; }, array());
```

That's all that's needed.

Comment: Maybe you read the question first :D In your answer the keys get lost!

Comment: Well then, here you go with a better solution. You just have to iterate the `+` operator over the array.

Answer (score 0):

i hope i can help you, first of all and do not take this wrong, you have got to investigate a little further, before asking for solutions, i strongly recommend you to go to www.php.net , http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php and search for array documentation, enough said you are looking at ways to loop through array, actually you are looking for the "foreach" statement, here i have made a simple solution which you can convert into function later:

```
<?php

$original = array
    (
        0 => array(554 => 'a'),
        1 => array(561 => 'b'),
        2 => array(574 => 'c'),
        );


/*$result = Array
(
    [554] => a
    [561] => b
    [574] => c
);*/

$result = array();


foreach ($original as $sub_array) {

    //this help us read first level array
    foreach ($sub_array as $subArrayKey=>$subArray) {
        // this help us read second level  array
        $result[$subArrayKey] = $subArray;

    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```